# Problem when using Machine learning to predict product delivery date

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, prediction

I am currently using machine learning model(written in Python3) to predict the product delivery date, but due to the nature of our business, customer always complain when the actual delivery date is later than the predicted delivery date. so I try to force the predicted date always later than the actual delivery date, but still as close to the actual date as possible. Can anyone advice me how to do this or any particular algorithm/methods that I can search for? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you use a prediction from a machine learning model, you're saying that this date is the most probably date that It will be delivered.

Every prediction has an error associated to real values. You can describe these errors as a normal distribution of the probability to happen over time. Thus, you have 50% of chance to the real value is before your prediction and 50% of chance to be after your prediction.

[image: errors distribution]

You'll hardly predict the exact value.

**But how can you overcome this?**

You can use the root mean squared error (RMSE). This metric will tell you "how far" your predictions are from the real values. So, if you add 2 times RMSE to your predictions before sending to users, the probability of the real value appears after your prediction is < 5%.

Comment: Hi Filipe, I am working on a similar project; I was wondering if you would say RMSE is a better metric compared to MAE

Comment: Hi @polmonroig, I think it depends on the context of the project. [This article has a good overview](https://medium.com/human-in-a-machine-world/mae-and-rmse-which-metric-is-better-e60ac3bde13d)